# ClassNotFoundException while executing mapreduce program

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, log4j

I was trying to execute the word count program in eclipse.

But while executing the program I am getting the following error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)          
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)

at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:914)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:150)
    at mapreducetest.main(mapreducetest.java:43)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "EventCounter".
13/09/02 11:17:18 INFO security.UserGroupInformation: JAAS Configuration already set up for Hadoop, not re-installing.
13/09/02 11:17:18 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
13/09/02 11:17:18 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/09/02 11:17:18 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/09/02 11:17:18 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
13/09/02 11:17:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/staging/hduser201346744/.staging/job_local201346744_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/thirdparty/guava/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.SocketCache.<init>(SocketCache.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:1597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:986)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:945)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:919)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1368)
    at mapreducetest.main(mapreducetest.java:59)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.apache.hadoop.thirdparty.guava.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter
> ```

You're missing a class on your classpath. Make sure all of Apache Hadoop is on your classpath. The jar in question is `hadoop-core-XXXXX.jar`.

Comment: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core.jar and /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1.jar files are there...can u specify which jar file to be included?

Comment: @user2728024 No, not without seeing your setup. are all on the actual classpath?

Comment: yeah .. these two jar files are there

Comment: @user2728024 Version mismatch? I unfortunately don't use Hadoop.

Comment: yeah it was a version mismatch its solved now... 

now am getting an error like this 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

i have already added commons-lang3-3.1 jar file..

Answer (score 0):

When you type `hadoop version` in the terminal what version of Hadoop do you get? Make sure you have same *hadoop-core*.jar* and all the libraries included in the Hadoop lib directory in the classpath for eclipse.

Comment: mine is Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.1
and the hadoop core jar files are also /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-tools-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1.jar and /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core.jar

Comment: Did you also include the other jars you have in your library?

Comment: yes.. i added all jars an now the error is 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at org.apache.avro.Protocol.main(Protocol.java:525)

Comment: Yup, now you have a issue in your Protocol.java line number 525 under main function. Check if you are accessing an array element at that position whose index doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to also make sure, jars  inside config/streaming are also included in the classpath.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.streaming.DumpTypedBytes i added all the jar files and now getting this error

is this a problem with my maven installation?

Comment: As I said, Did you put int the classpath the hadoop-streaming-*.jar. It should be somewhere in the hadoop contrib/ directory.

Comment: yes...is it a version problem... am using cdh4 and my eclipse is indigo.. should i use a higher version of eclipse?

Comment: yeah it was a version mismatch its solved now... now am getting an error like this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils i have already added commons-lang3-3.1 jar file..

Comment: In commons-lang3-3.1 jar, I guess, you don't have StringUtils in org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils but in org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils. Please verify it once. May be you should fall back to a lesser version for e.g.: commons-lang2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the jar files to your eclipse project

1.) Under HADOOP_HOME directory
2.) Under HADOOP_HOME/lib directory

Try and see if it works.

However you might face some more issues further if you are using eclipse under Windows to run MR programs.

Comment: i added all jar files now am getting the error

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at org.apache.avro.Protocol.main(Protocol.java:525)

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.streaming.DumpTypedBytes

i added all the jar files and now getting this error...its a program that i copy pasted from apachehadoop's site