# calss not found error in mapreduce program

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a beginer in mapreduce programming.
I was executing a mapreduce program in eclipse.While running a program am getting this error
(i have included commons-logging jar file)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.DumpTypedBytes.main(DumpTypedBytes.java:142)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

please help!!
thanks in advance

Comment: Similar [already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18566503/1424875). We can't track down all of the libraries for you.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as you asked before. Missing libraries. Install [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) and [all of the other dependencies](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/dependency-analysis.html). This includes the "used but undeclared" ones.

- log4j
- slf4j
- mockito
- google inject extensions
- protobuf
- junit
- Apache commons IO
- com.google.inject
- Jersey
- Jersey: Contribs
- Google Guava
- Commons Lang
- jaxb
- apache commons compress
- jackson
- jackson-mapper-asl

Alternatively copy all of the jars from the `lib` folder.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut My apologies, I am not familiar with the distribution of Hadoop.

Comment: No problem, just wanted to tell you about it ;)